# syntax error, unexpected 'head' (T_STRING)

Tags: php, class

I creating a class for generating a html web page.
I am now facing an error. 
I can't find where I have done wrong maybe I have typo can anyone help me? 
I would be appreciated.
It is something that I didn't declare or anything I didn't add into it.

```
 /*Singleton Design Pattern*/
class WEBPAGE{

private $title = "";
private $style = [];

/*Store Head, Body, Footer Content*/
private head = "";
private body = "";
private footer = "";

private function __constructor(){
    $this->$title = "";
    $this->$style = [];
}

private function styleGenerator($style){
    $generated_style = [];
}

private function styleTag($src){
    return '<link rel="stylesheet" href="'.$src.'">';
}

public static function getInstance()
{ 
    if(!self::$instance)
    {
        self::$instance = new self();
    }

    return self::$instance;
}

public function ouput(){
    //styleGenerator($this->$style);
    echo "My blank page";
}

}

?>
```

Comment: Missing dollar signs on your head, body, and footer declarations.

Comment: owh okay stupid mistake thanks @Gavin

Comment: `$this->$title = "";` should be `$this->title = "";` same for `$this->$style = [];`

Comment: `private function __constructor()` or `private function __construct()`??

Answer (score 0):

Add $ sign to all before,missing $

```
private head = "";
private body = "";
private footer = "";
```

Code should as following

```
private $head = "";
private $body = "";
private $footer = "";
```

Also remove $ at $this->$title and $this->$style

```
private function __constructor(){
    $this->title = "";
    $this->style = [];
}
```